# test case not covering in cobertura

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, testcase, powermockito

```
public class MyUtil {
    public static Properties loadProperties() throws Exception {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = MyUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTY_FILENAME);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

I have written test case for the above method, when I ran as test case in eclipse it's passing and when I debug `loadProperties()` is not getting called and `cobertura report` is showing as uncovered code.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyUtil.class, Properties.class })

@Test
public void testLoadProperties() throws Exception{
    String fileName = "application.properties";
    Properties mockProps = PowerMockito.mock(Properties.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Properties.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Properties.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockProps);
    InputStream mockInputStream = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyUtil.class);
    ClassLoader mockClassLoader = Mockito.mock(ClassLoader.class);
    PowerMockito.when(MyUtil.class.getClassLoader()).thenReturn(mockClassLoader);
    PowerMockito.when(mockClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)).thenReturn(mockInputStream);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mockProps).load((InputStream)Mockito.any());
    MyUtil.loadProperties();
    //assertNotNull("Not Null", MyUtil.loadProperties()); //assert failing
}
```

what should I change to make sure that my code actually covers in code coverage?

Answer (score 1):

It's old well-known issue that PowerMock breaks code coverage tools:
https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/94

In current moment, there is only one way to get code coverage JaCoCo Offline instrumenting 
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo